# Classes wrapping

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance

I am new to OOP and java world and trying to understand the concepts. 
There are three separate feature projects, each having their own abstract classes and interfaces. I am facing difficulty in wrapping these projects in my test automation solution. I am thinking of using Abstract factory pattern to create features abstract classes and interface in my test automation project. How can i wrap the classes in my project without direct referencing the feature classes.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you maybe taking an over complex route.....  The solution might be simpler:

Each project should be (at least) in its own package.

Packaging allows java to group classes together under certain namespaces so that their features do not intrude into other classes.

"A package provides a unique namespace for the types it contains.
Classes in the same package can access each other's package-access members."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package